# Question about two homeomorphic closed manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was studying about algebraic topology with my study group.
So, there was a question that held all of the study members confused.

> If two closed manifolds are homeomorphic, they must have same
>   dimension.

It sounds really trivial but we did not find any good way to prove this problem.

Any suggestions to start the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define the dimension of a closed manifold?

Comment: well I would not say it is completely trivial. I assume you are interested in the finite dimensional case and the dimension is defined by the dimension of some $ \mathbb{R}^n$ to which the manifold is locally homeomorphic. Then it is sufficient to show that if $\mathbb{R}^n $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m $ this implies $m=n$. Homology theory can do that for you.

Comment: I might be confused but: If $X$ and $Y$ (closed manifolds) are homeomorphic, and $X$ locally homeomorphic to $R^n$, then we can compose these maps to show that $Y$ is locally homeomorphic to $R^n$.

Comment: @Ryan the point is to show that this dimension is invariant under a homeomorphism, that is that there is no homeoemorphism which changes the dimension. This fact is one of the celebrated results of the algebraic topology machinery. Keywords you might google are invariance of the dimension and invariance of the domain.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: Invariance of domain is even harder to show than $\mathbb R^n \not \cong \mathbb R^k$ for $k \neq n$, which would be sufficent in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, as the dimension is defined locally, the problem is also a local one:

(note that $dim$ is a locally constant function, hence it our manifolds are connected, the dimension is globally the same)

If you have not heard about homology, you can probably show $\mathbb R \not \cong \mathbb R^2$. Maybe also (still not very hard) that $\mathbb R^2 \not \cong \mathbb R^3$ (and of course $\mathbb R \not \cong \mathbb R^3$). Beyond that it gets very hard and highly non trivial.

This is usually one of the first examples in lectures about homology, to show how powerful the presented tool is. You will get a homotopy invariant (in particular a topological invariant) which yields the following groups (indexed with $n\geq 0$) applied to the desired spaces: 
$$
H_i(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n -0) \cong \begin{cases} \mathbb Z, & i=0,n-1 \\ 0,& \text{else} \end{cases}
$$

Hence you get that $H_*(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n-0)=H_*(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R^k-0)$ (i.e. all groups with same index coincide)$ \implies $k=n$, in particular there is no homeomorphism for euclidean space of different dimension (it would induce an iso on homology).

Also note that there is a very important theorem called "Invariance of domain", but also that this is harder to show than the statement above.